# Deleting message not working when back pressed or app exit

Tags: java, android, firebase, messaging

I'm working with a messaging app that deletes the message in a given time. The message is deleted only when the current activity is not close. So when I back pressed the message will not be deleted.

Chat Activity:

```
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("ID", ID);
        intent.putExtra("MessageID", MessageID);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, reqID, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  System.currentTimeMillis() + duration, pendingIntent);
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
    int notifyID = 1;
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
    String id= intent.getStringExtra("ID");
    String messageID= intent.getStringExtra("MessageID");


    mData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Global.CHATS);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mData.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(id).child(Global.Messages).child(messageID).removeValue();
    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notif", importance);
    Notification notification =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.default_ic)
                    .setContentText("Your message was deleted").build();

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

    // Issue the notification.
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID , notification);
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.BroadcastReceiver"/>
```

It seems that when I close the app or back press it from the Chat activity, only the notification is being executed but for the deleting of message it only deletes in the current activity and does not work when app is exit or back pressed.